# Проблема взаимодействия Клиента и Сервера по TCP

Tags: java, клиент-сервер, tcp-ip

Есть **Сервер** с множеством подключений, и **Клиент**, которые должны просто переписываться друг с другом.

На **Сервер** всё доходит, а вот к **Клиенту** - нет. В чём проблема?

Класс, реализующий **Сервер**:

```
public class ServerChat
{

    public static Thread StartServerT = new Thread(new StartServer());
    public static Thread ServerSOutT = new Thread(new ServerSOut());
    public static Thread ExitT = new Thread(new Exit());
    public static LinkedList<DataInputStream> LLin =
        new LinkedList<DataInputStream>();
    public static LinkedList<DataOutputStream> LLout =
        new LinkedList<DataOutputStream>();
    public static LinkedList<Socket> LLS =
        new LinkedList<Socket>();
    public static ServerSocket ss;
    public static boolean check = true;
    public static boolean ChekIn = false;
    public static int port = 6666;
    public static int num = 0;
    public static int in = 0;
    public static String line = null;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Server start work");
            ss = new ServerSocket(port);
            StartServerT.setPriority(6);
            StartServerT.start();
            ExitT.setPriority(8);
            ExitT.start();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Server not run");
        }
    }

    public static class StartServer implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println("Client connect run");
                while (true)
                { // ждем подключения от клиентов
                    Socket socket = ss.accept();
                    LLS.add(socket);
                    if (socket.isConnected())
                    {
                        // Для каждого клиента создаём DataInputStream и DataOutputStream
                        OutWriteSocket();
                        System.out.println("Client connect " + socket.getInetAddress());
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("StartServer error");
            }
        }

        public void OutWriteSocket()
        {
            try
            {
                InputStream inIS = (LLS.get(num)).getInputStream();
                OutputStream outIS = (LLS.get(num)).getOutputStream();
                DataInputStream ind = new DataInputStream(inIS);
                DataOutputStream outd = new DataOutputStream(outIS);
                LLin.add(ind); // Записываем всё в LinkedList
                LLout.add(outd);
                num = num + 1;
                System.out.println("Number of client " + in);
                in = in + 1;

                // Новый клиентский Thread для для приёма данных
                Thread ServerSInT = new Thread(new ServerSIn());
                ServerSInT.start(); // Запускаем его
                if ( ! ServerSOutT.isAlive())
                {
                    ServerSOutT.start(); // Запускаем Thread для вывода
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("OutWriteSocket error");
            }
        }
    }

    public static class ServerSIn implements Runnable
    {
        // Thread ввода
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println("ServerSIn run");
                int w = in - 1;
                while (true)
                {
                    line = LLin.get(w).readUTF(); // Принимаем данные
                    // При значении ChekIn == true Thread вывода начинает
                    // проверять значение line и отправлять его
                    ChekIn = true; 

                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("ServerSIn error");
            }
        }
    }

    public static class ServerSOut implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println("ServerSOut run");
                while (true)
                {
                    if (ChekIn)
                    {
                        System.out.println(line);
                        for (int i = 0; i < LLout.size(); i++)
                        {
                            System.out.println(line);
                            LLout.get(i).writeUTF(line);
                            // LLout.get(i).flush();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("ServerSOut error");
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Exit implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                BufferedReader reader =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                System.out.println("If you want off server write - 'exit'");
                while (check)
                {
                    String line = reader.readLine();
                    if (line.equals("exit"))
                    {
                        StartServerT.stop();
                        ServerSOutT.stop();
                        System.out.println("Server Stop");
                        check = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("You dont maik off server");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Класс, реализующий **Клиент**:

```
public class ClientChat
{

    public static Thread t1 = new Thread(new ConectToServer());
    public static Thread InServerT = new Thread(new InServer());
    public static DataInputStream in;
    public static String line = null;
    public static boolean CheckOut = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        t1.start();
    }

    public static class ConectToServer implements Runnable
    {
        public static int serverPort = 6666;

        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println("Connect to server...");
                ConectToServerURL();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("No connect to server tray again");
            }
        }

        public void ConectToServerURL() throws IOException
        {
            try
            {
                String address = "127.0.0.1";

                System.out.println("You connect to server");
                System.out.println("If you wont exit write 'exit' ");
                InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(address);
                Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress, serverPort);

                InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
                OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();

                in = new DataInputStream(sin);
                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);
                InServerT.start();

                BufferedReader keyboard =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

                while (true)
                {
                    line = keyboard.readLine();
                    if (line.equals("exit"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("You exit");
                        t1.stop();
                    }
                    out.writeUTF(line);
                    out.flush();
                    CheckOut = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                System.out.println("Client not maik connect to server");
            }
        }
    }

    public static class InServer implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (CheckOut)
                    {
                        line = in.readUTF();
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("InServer error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ваш код выглядит плохо. Слишком много вложенных классов - вынесите в отдельные файлы те, которые можно. Статические поля и коллекции (все эти `LinkedList`) там, где нужно использовать поля отдельных экземпляров или вообще локальные переменные. Зачем-то создаёте потоки для того, что можно выполнить в основном потоке (в методе `main`). Нет потокобезопасности. И наконец, названия полей и методов должны быть с маленькой буквы (так принято в java).

Comment: А что по поводу ошибки? Код ещё буде приводиться в порядок.

Comment: Сейчас слишком много ошибок. Приведите код в порядок, тогда можно будет что-то сказать.